# Sum of Harmonic series: $ 1+\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} + \frac {1}{4} + \cdots + \frac {1}{50}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

How to find the sum of this series : $ 1+\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3} + \frac {1}{4} + \cdots + \frac {1}{50}$